# facebook tab page not showing up

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have recently attempted to make a facebook tab for a client of mine. The problem that i'm having is that the website that should be showing on the page that the tab redirects me to is not showing, and instead it shows this grey box with a sad face icon in the middle. I have never had this happen before.

The link to the tab is https://www.facebook.com/suzannehannafanpage/app_1418157538415227
and the page that it should be showing is http://ctrnetwork.com/profile/suzannehanna

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any other browser than Chrome (which shows the sad face icon in situations like this) would tell you that you don’t have a valid SSL certificate for your app …